# SegmentFault on File pointer between functions

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, function-pointers

Before you say, yes I've checked nearly all the other postings, none are working.

My program has been giving me a segmentation error for hours and hours and nothing is fixing it. I debugged it to the point where I found it's in the file pointer. From what I know, it's because of the way I'm either using the file pointer in the 'makeArray' function or from the file closing statement. I don't really understand how it's not working because I used my last program as reference for this and it runs perfectly fine but this one won't.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROWS 12
#define COLS 8

void makeArray(FILE*, int [][COLS]);
int getScore(int [][COLS], int, int);
int getMonthMax(int [][COLS], int);
int getYearMax(int [][COLS]);
float getMonthAvg(int [][COLS], int);
float getYearAvg(int [][COLS]);
int toursMissed(int [][COLS]);
void displayMenu();
int processRequest(int [][COLS], int);
void printArray(int [][COLS]);

int main(){

    int scoresArray[ROWS][COLS];
    int choice, constant = 0;

    FILE* inputPtr;
    inputPtr = fopen("scores.txt", "r");
    makeArray(inputPtr, scoresArray);
    fclose(inputPtr);

    while(constant == 0){
        displayMenu();
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        processRequest(scoresArray, choice);
    }
    return 0;
}

void makeArray(FILE* inputPtr, int scoresArray[][COLS]){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++){
            fscanf(inputPtr, "%d", &scoresArray[i][j]);         
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

I've tried moving the file pointers to every different spot in the code and nothing. I don't necessarily want you to just give me the answer but I want an explanation of why it's happening in this specific code because every other post I've checked and their results don't match up to mine.

Also the input file is

```
26 35 25 92 0 6 47 68 26 72 67 33 84 28
22 36 53 66 23 86 36 75 14 62 43 11 42 5
14 58 0 23 30 87 80 81 13 35 94 45 1 53
14 55 46 19 13 0 25 28 66 86 69 0 81 15
55 60 26 70 22 36 15 67 62 16 71 7 29 92
84 37 2 30 7 5 4 50 0 67 2 53 69 87
8 23 74 58 86 0 78 88 85 12 1 52 999
```

Comment: Check that `inputPtr` isn't `NULL` after `fopen()`... could be failing to open the file.  Also, you should check the return from `fscanf()`.

Comment: @Dmitri I had that in earlier and it was opening fine. Just tried again to double check, it is still opening. Also, what do you mean by check the return of 'fscanf?'

Comment: The return value from `fscanf()` would tell you whether it actually read a value for you, and also whether it encountered an error reading the file (like trying to read past EOF).

Comment: If you're referring to whether the input file is successfully scanning into the array, that is working. When I run the program in Dev C++, it works fine. However, the compiler my University uses is giving a Segmentation Fault.

Comment: Did you check that `inputPtr` was not `NULL` in Dev C++ or at your university?  Try leaving the error checks in place and printing a message on error... if the file is opening correctly, there's probably something wrong in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: is it possible for you to open core dump file in debugger gdb or something and see where exactly seg-fault occurs? BTW there are 14 columns in your file and not 12

Comment: also 7 rows not 8 - maybe you run out of input data - try reducing ROWS and COLS - but 7x14 >8x12....so this may not be the problem...

Comment: @Dmitri I honestly don't know if it was checking for NULL or changing the text file because I tried them both at the same time. But thanks a ton for sticking around and helping me out. It means a lot! Have a good one!

Comment: @SameerNaik I solved it, but yeah the input file she gave is is faulted in a lot of ways. She didn't give it to us in the order it's supposed to show on the program which is nonsense but she included an example output in the instructions and mine matches.

Comment: @tom Yeah, the input file she gave us doesn't match the order it's supposed to be in. I should've included the example she gave and it would've made sense, but it's all solved now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if your university compiler is picky about the input file - can you remove all new lines from a copy of your input file and try running with the copied modified input file --- so it is just a stream of numbers --- see if this sorts it out...

........ in my experience of scanf and fscanf these functions can be a bit fragile if the input does not run exactly the way you say it will in the format part - here "%d" does not tell fscanf about new line characters....

Comment: If that's it, wouldn't `fscanf()` just fail to read new values into the array, but without crashing?

Comment: That actually worked... So I've spent the past 11 hours trying nonsense because the input file she gave us was faulted.... wonderful. Anyways, I appreciate the assistance! You don't know how happy this makes me!

Comment: @dimitri I agree with your point - but as it was compiler specific it had to be some sort of weird default/non-default behaviour in my opinion

Comment: @tom Or another function crashing later because of the random values left in the array, possibly?

Comment: @KyleSteward the issue was probably that you needed to let fscanf know about the newline characters in the file - but the first compiler you used didn't worry about the newline characters.

Comment: @KyleSteward in my experience of scanf and fscanf these functions can be a bit fragile if the input does not run exactly the way you say it will in the format part - here "%d" does not tell fscanf about new line characters....